# Google analytics core reporting api pageview label?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to send some specific data to filter later on when using the GA core api. For instance when I track an event I can pass some parameters like so.

```
ga('send', 'event', {
    eventCategory: data.category,
    eventAction: data.action,
    eventLabel: data.label || null,
    eventValue: data.value || null,
    nonInteraction: data.interaction === false ? false : true
});
```

I can then filter these later on when making requests for the data. In particular I'm trying to track item id's which I store in the `eventLabel` fields. For events everything is good.

The part I'm having issues with is in filtering page views, sessions, etc. The call for that looks like:

```
ga('set', 'page', data.path);
ga('send', 'pageview', {eventLabel: 'test'});
```

The `eventLabel` in this case doesn't seem to work. I can't use filter by `pagePath` becasue I'm using pretty url's. I need to explicitly set the id in the page views if possible. Or some alternate method that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pageview` command doesn't take an `eventLabel` parameter, only a `title`, `location`, or `page`, as mentioned here https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages#pageview_fields. Perhaps try using a custom dimension for the item ID instead.

Also, might need to double check your nonInteraction logic for your event. If `data.interaction` is false, I would think this means it's not interactive, thus making `nonInteraction` true (and vice versa).